# Do I need to rebuilt a React app after making changes to the source code?

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

I have just completed my portfolio website in react app and use npm run build command to generate a build folder and used that build folder to host my portfolio on netlify, but now after some reviews from my colleagues I have decided to change some things on the code. Do I have to run build command again in the terminal to create a new build folder  with updated changes so that I can host it again?

I have seen online tutorials but I couldn't understand it there, that's why I am asking here from experienced people, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've hosted it as a Reactjs app then **you don't have to** run `npm build` again, netlify would automatically run it on every change to the github repo, given the correct preference have be set. To ensure you can run `deploy` again from your netlify console. [Deploy Guide](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/29/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-on-netlify/)

In case you've hosted just with the files inside the build folder choosing HTML template in netlify, **you'd have to** run `npm build` every time you make changes to your app code and update the same to your github repo/netlify.

Comment: Thank you so much for this precise and accurate answer sir.